# python sort using custom function using two objects

Tags: python

How would I able to do custom key function sort that needs two objects. I have a family of objects that implement a function but that function needs another family of objects to get the result (Score). And then the sort is based on that score. See code

```
class AdoptionCenter(object):
  name=''
  species_types={}
  location=()
  def __init__(self, name, species_types, location):
    self.name = name
    self.species_types = species_types
    lst=list(location)
    lst[0]=lst[0]+1.0-1.0
    lst[1]=lst[1]+1.0-1.0
    t = tuple(lst)
    self.location = t

  def get_name(self):
      return self.name
  def get_location(self):
      return self.location
  def get_species_count(self):
      ss = dict(filter(lambda (a,bc): bc>0, self.species_types.items()))
      #dict((k, v) for k, v in ss.items() if all(x < 5 for x in v))
      return ss
  def get_number_of_species(self,species_name):
      return self.species_types.get(species_name,0) 
  def adopt_pet(self,species_name):
      if ( self.species_types.get(species_name) >0):
        self.species_types[species_name]=self.species_types[species_name]-1



class Adopter(object):
    name=''
    desired_species=''
    def __init__(self, name, desired_species):
        self.name=name
        self.desired_species=desired_species

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_desired_species(self):
        return self.desired_species
    def get_score(self,adoption_center):
        score=1.0*adoption_center.get_number_of_species(self.desired_species)
        return score

class FlexibleAdopter(Adopter,object):
    considered_species=[]


    def __init__(self, name, desired_species, considered_species):
        super(FlexibleAdopter,self).__init__(name, desired_species)
        self.considered_species=considered_species

    def get_score(self,adoption_center):
        s1=super(FlexibleAdopter, self).get_score(adoption_center)
        s2=0
        for k in self.considered_species:
            xx=adoption_center.get_number_of_species(k)
            if xx is None:
                xx=0
            s2=s2+0.3*xx
        scr=s1+s2
        return scr

class FearfulAdopter(Adopter,object):
    feared_species =''
    def __init__(self, name, desired_species, feared_species):
        super(FearfulAdopter,self).__init__(name, desired_species)
        self.feared_species=feared_species        

    def get_score(self,adoption_center):
        s1=super(FearfulAdopter, self).get_score(adoption_center)
        s2=adoption_center.get_number_of_species(self.feared_species)

        if s2 is None:
            s2=0

        scr=s1-0.3*s2

        if scr <0:
            return 0.0
        else:
            return scr

adopter = MedicatedAllergicAdopter("One", "Cat", ['Dog', 'Horse'], {"Dog": .5, "Horse": 0.2})
adopter2 = Adopter("Two", "Cat")
adopter3 = FlexibleAdopter("Three", "Horse", ["Lizard", "Cat"])
adopter4 = FearfulAdopter("Four","Cat","Dog")
adopter5 = SluggishAdopter("Five","Cat", (1,2))
adopter6 = AllergicAdopter("Six", "Cat", "Dog") 

ac = AdoptionCenter("Place1", {"Mouse": 12, "Dog": 2}, (1,1))
ac2 = AdoptionCenter("Place2", {"Cat": 12, "Lizard": 2}, (3,5))
ac3 = AdoptionCenter("Place3", {"Horse": 25, "Dog": 9}, (-2,10))

def get_mkey(Adopter):
    return Adopter.get_score()

lst1=[adopter, adopter2, adopter3, adopter4, adopter5, adopter6]
sorted(lst1, key=Adopter.get_score(ac))

# how to test get_adopters_for_advertisement
get_adopters_for_advertisement(ac, [adopter, adopter2, adopter3, adopter4, adopter5, adopter6], 10)
# you can print the name and score of each item in the list returned

adopter4 = FearfulAdopter("Four","Cat","Dog")
adopter5 = SluggishAdopter("Five","Cat", (1,2))
adopter6 = AllergicAdopter("Six", "Lizard", "Cat") 

ac = AdoptionCenter("Place1", {"Cat": 12, "Dog": 2}, (1,1))
ac2 = AdoptionCenter("Place2", {"Cat": 12, "Lizard": 2}, (3,5))
ac3 = AdoptionCenter("Place3", {"Cat": 40, "Dog": 4}, (-2,10))
ac4 = AdoptionCenter("Place4", {"Cat": 33, "Horse": 5}, (-3,0))
ac5 = AdoptionCenter("Place5", {"Cat": 45, "Lizard": 2}, (8,-2))
ac6 = AdoptionCenter("Place6", {"Cat": 23, "Dog": 7, "Horse": 5}, (-10,10))

# how to test get_ordered_adoption_center_list
get_ordered_adoption_center_list(adopter4, [ac,ac2,ac3,ac4,ac5,ac6])                            
# you can print the name and score of each item in the list returned
```

Comment: The code in your example is a bit too complicated and it obscures the problem. Can you simplify it into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, it looks like you have a list of objects that are subclasses of Adopter, and you want to sort them using the `get_score()` method.  The `get_score()` method is different for each subclass and the method takes a parameter.

Change this:

```
sorted(lst1, key=Adopter.get_score(ac))
```

to this:

```
lst1.sort(key=lambda a:a.get_score(ac))
```

This calls `get_score()` on the appropriate subclass and passes `ac` as an argument.

Note: `sorted()` returns a sorted copy of a list.  It does not sort the list in-place.  Because the code didn't assign the result of `sorted(...)`, it was discarded.